# Bumblebee daemon dont start on Ubuntu 13.04 with T530

Tags: 13.04, thinkpad, bumblebee

im trying to setup my T530 with Intel HD 4000 und nVidia NVS 5400M (1 GB) mit Optimus.

Installed latest bumblebee with bumblebee-nvidia from the stable ppa and also installed primus.

I set up the Bios to Integrated Mode, do be able to boot into Ubuntu. And also turned on the switch for Autodetect.

If i run something like `optirun glxspheres` I get the error:

```
[ 1361.672499] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ 1361.672564] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

If I switch to Optimus or Discrete Mode Ubuntu boots into bash mode. `startx` stops with an error.

Any idea or suggestion?
best regards
denym

Comment: how did you install bumblebee

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/297634/cant-install-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-11-1/297643#297643

Comment: its for 11.10... the linux-header problem is fixed since 12.10

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command in terminal:

`sudo service bumblebeed restart`.

It should start the bumblebee daemon if it has not already been started. After that, try to run the `optirun` command again.